# Nodejs blog site wont show current email in the Edit Settings Page

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My nodejs blog site wont show my current email in the Edit Settings page.  It only shows the correct Name.  For Email Edit User settings: it shows: [object Object]  The correct email should show for each email from mongodb.  Not sure if I need app.get and app.post as well.

app.js:

```
app.get('/editUserSettings', (req, res) => {
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
            const email = User.findOne(req.body.email)
            if (!err) {
                res.render("editUserSettings", {
                    user: user, email: email
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

editUserSettings.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>

<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">Edit my Profile </div>
    <form class="ui form" action="/editUserSettings/<%= currentUser._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        
        <div class="field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=currentUser%>" >
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<%=email %>" >
        </div>
        <button class="ui violet basic button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

Comment: (Irrelevant but) you should sanitize user inputs before directly sending them into database query if there is no middle layer for this already.

Answer (score 0):

your User.findeOne returns an object with your properties defined in the Schema and a unique id to your database entry, try a console.log(email) after the findOne line, it should log something like:

```
{
  _id: XXXXXXXXXXXX,
  email: example@youremail.de
}
```

also if you are using mongoose as a client for mongodb you need to async await your code because User.findOne returns a promise, maybe contact me on my discord lausnens#6598, there i could help you a bit better :)

Comment: Hi, I sent you request in discord blackmesa1983#7828  BTW I added the async to my function and did console.log(email) and I noticed it's showing my first email I registered in my mongodb.  For example when I log on with a second account the username shows correctly but it shows the original email address which does not match the username

Comment: I think it should show the correct mail, did you check your database? Maybe every account has the same email in our database.

Comment: There are 3 different email accounts.  when I log on to any account, it shows the same email for all 3 but the name is different.

Comment: Pls do the following, 
Go into your database run ```use YOUR_DATABASENAME``` then run ```db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find()``` there you see al entries, check the emails there.

Comment: I did run db.users.find().pretty()  I see 3 email accounts with 3 different emails,  When I log on with my main gmail account(registered user in my blog) I see the correct one, but the other 2 usernames I log on to shows the original main gmail account.  It's showing the same email address for 3 different users.